# Logging an unknown number of floats in a python C extension

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I'm using python to set up a computationally intense simulation, then running it in a custom built C-extension and finally processing the results in python. During the simulation, I want to store a fixed-length number of floats (C doubles converted to PyFloatObjects) representing my variables at every time step, but I don't know how many time steps there will be in advance. Once the simulation is done, I need to pass back the results to python in a form where the data logged for each individual variable is available as a list-like object (for example a (wrapper around a) continuous array, piece-wise continuous array or column in a matrix with a fixed stride).

At the moment I'm creating a dictionary mapping the name of each variable to a list containing PyFloatObject objects. This format is perfect for working with in the post-processing stage but I have a feeling the creation stage could be a lot faster.

Time is quite crucial since the simulation is a computationally heavy task already. I expect that a combination of A. buying lots of memory and B. setting up your experiment wisely will allow the entire log to fit in the RAM. However, with my current dict-of-lists solution keeping every variable's log in a continuous section of memory would require a lot of copying and overhead.

My question is: *What is a clever, low-level way of quickly logging gigabytes of doubles in memory with minimal space/time overhead, that still translates to a neat python data structure?*

---

**Clarification:** when I say "logging", I mean storing until after the simulation. Once that's done a post-processing phase begins and in most cases I'll only store the resulting graphs. So I don't actually need to store the numbers on disk.

---

**Update:** In the end, I changed my approach a little and added the log (as a dict mapping variable names to sequence types) to the function parameters. This allows you to pass in objects such as lists or array.arrays or anything that has an append method. This adds a little time overhead because I'm using the PyObject_CallMethodObjArgs function to call the Append method instead of PyList_Append or similar. Using arrays allows you to reduce the memory load, which appears to be the best I can do short of writing my own expanding storage type. Thanks everyone!

Comment: Have you looked at numpy? Creating a numpy array of doubles instead of a normal PyList of PyFloatObjects is actually easier from C, as well as faster on both sides and more memory-efficient.

Comment: Also, do you actually need to have gigabytes of doubles in memory and find a way to dump them to disk, or can you use an on-disk structure in the first place? (Which could be as simple as an mmap of a C array of doubles, which you interpret from Python via the `struct` module.)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! Numpy arrays are fixed size though, so I could only do this efficiently by wrapping a numpy array around a block of C-data _after_ storing it in space I allocated myself using some kind of home-brewed expanding array structure. I would actually really enjoy writing that code but I wonder if generations of C-programmers haven't already made something faster than I'd come up with :)

Comment: Can you use C++ instead of C? Because a `std::vector` does the auto-expanding automatically, and you can access its contents as a C array to feed into numpy when it's done being expanded. Or, alternatively, use a std::deque or SGI-STL rope or other stride-based container for less copying along the way.

Comment: True! Following the answer given below I think the python array module would do the same though. I'd have to test to see which is faster in a typical use-case. (Something I haven't really mentioned is that I'm compiling the C-extension on the fly using distutils. The ansi-C compiler is really fast so this incurs minimal overhead. Compiling C++ is a little harder...) I was also wondering if there was a benefit to creating a single data structure (with a fixed-length stride) and expanding that, especially if people here have experience in doing so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want to consider doing this in Cython, instead of as a C extension module.  Cython is smart, and lets you do things in a pretty pythonic way, even though it at the same time lets you use C datatypes and python datatypes.

Have you checked out the array module?  It allows you to store lots of scalar, homogeneous types in a single collection.

If you're truly "logging" these, and not just returning them to CPython, you might try opening a file and fprintf'ing them.

BTW, realloc might be your friend here, whether you go with a C extension module or Cython.

Comment: 1. I'll definitely consider Cython in the future, but I'm not sure I'd gain a speed benefit worth the extra hassle.

2. The array module looks like a great first step, maybe even the final answer. Thanks!

3. If that's what the word "logging" means, then I'm not logging them. If you know a better way to describe what I'm doing here I'd love to hear about it, google searches involving the stem "log" all lead to page after page on text logs, log rotation and logarithms.

4. realloc is a good friend to have, but since I want to return a python object it's quite likely I won't be alloc-ing myself.

Comment: Hmmm... As much as I'd love to use it, the array module doesn't appear to have a C API :-(

Answer (score 1):

This is going to be more a huge dump of ideas rather than a consistent answer, because it sounds like that's what you're looking for. If not, I apologize.

The main thing you're trying to avoid here is storing billions of PyFloatObjects in memory. There are a few ways around that, but they all revolve on storing billions of plain C doubles instead, and finding some way to expose them to Python as if they were sequences of PyFloatObjects.

To make Python (or someone else's module) do the work, you can use a numpy array, a standard library array, a simple hand-made wrapper on top of the struct module, or ctypes. (It's a bit odd to use ctypes to deal with an extension module, but there's nothing stopping you from doing it.) If you're using struct or ctypes, you can even go beyond the limits of your memory by creating a huge file and mmapping in windows into it as needed.

To make your C module do the work, instead of actually returning a list, return a custom object that meets the sequence protocol, so when someone calls, say, foo.**getitem**(i) you convert _array[i] to a PyFloatObject on the fly.

Another advantage of mmap is that, if you're creating the arrays iteratively, you can create them by just streaming to a file, and then use them by mmapping the resulting file back as a block of memory.

Otherwise, you need to handle the allocations. If you're using the standard array, it takes care of auto-expanding as needed, but otherwise, you're doing it yourself. The code to do a realloc and copy if necessary isn't that difficult, and there's lots of sample code online, but you do have to write it. Or you may want to consider building a strided container that you can expose to Python as if it were contiguous even though it isn't. (You can do this directly via the complex buffer protocol, but personally I've always found that harder than writing my own sequence implementation.) If you can use C++, vector is an auto-expanding array, and deque is a strided container (and if you've got the SGI STL rope, it may be an even better strided container for the kind of thing you're doing).

As the other answer pointed out, Cython can help for some of this. Not so much for the "exposing lots of floats to Python" part; you can just move pieces of the Python part into Cython, where they'll get compiled into C. If you're lucky, all of the code that needs to deal with the lots of floats will work within the subset of Python that Cython implements, and the only things you'll need to expose to actual interpreted code are higher-level drivers (if even that).